# UserControl not filling width of ItemsPresenter in customised DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to add a custom header above the cells of a DataGrid. I want the header to scroll with the content of the DataGrid, so I don't want to customise the DataGrid's column headers because these are outside of the ScrollViewer. The idea is to create a similar appearance to a web page (I.e. Google Classroom) where you have a page header at the top containing some information about the class, and a feed of posts from the teachers and students underneath.

I've taken the standard control template for the DataGrid (produced by Visual Studio) and placed a Grid around the ItemsPresenter. The first row of that grid contains my custom header (in a nested Grid) and the second row contains the original ItemsPresenter. The problem is the ItemsPresenter is filling the available width, but the 'items' it displays (custom UserControl named AnnouncementView) are not filling the width of the ItemsPresenter. So as you can see in the picture below, you can't read anything in the presented AnnouncementView's.

[image: Picture of layout problem]

**DataGrid**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Announcements"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        HeadersVisibility="None"
        GridLinesVisibility="None"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Visibility="{Binding AnnouncementsIsVisible}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding CMAnnouncements}" Style="{DynamicResource AnnouncementsDataGrid}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:AnnouncementView />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**DataGrid Style**

```
<Color x:Key="ClassroomHeaderColor">#FF2222FF</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ClassroomHeaderBrush" Color="{StaticResource ClassroomHeaderColor}" />

<Style x:Key="AnnouncementsDataGrid" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF688CAF"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="1000" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="VisibleWhenSelected"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="false">
                        <ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Button Command="{x:Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}" Focusable="false" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                    <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                    <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="2" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ScrollViewer.Template>
<!--#region Custom Modification -->
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Border Background="{StaticResource ClassroomHeaderBrush}" CornerRadius="8" Grid.Row="0">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition MinHeight="25" Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition MinHeight="20"  Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="16" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding CMCourse.Course.Name}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                                    <Label Content="{Binding CMCourse.Course.Section}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                                    <Label Content="Class code" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding CMCourse.Course.EnrollmentCode}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />

                                    <!-- Creation and Update times -->
                                    <Label Content="Created:" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                                    <Label Content="{Binding CMCourse.Course.CreationTime, StringFormat=g}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" />
                                    <Label Content="Last Updated:" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                                    <Label Content="{Binding CMCourse.Course.UpdateTime, StringFormat=g}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" />

                                    <!-- Course State -->
                                    <Label Content="Course State:" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2">
                                        <ComboBox x:Name="NewCourseState"
                                                    IsReadOnly="True"
                                                    ItemsSource="{Binding NewCourseState}"
                                                    SelectedValuePath="Name"
                                                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNewCourseState, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                    DisplayMemberPath="Name">
                                            <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                                <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                                                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                                                </Style>
                                            </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        </ComboBox>
                                        <Button x:Name="ChangeCourseState" Content="Apply"/>
                                    </StackPanel>

                                    <!-- More Details Expander -->
                                    <Expander Header="Details" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Label Content="Subject" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                                            <Label Content="{Binding CMCourse.Course.Subject, TargetNullValue='No subject set'}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
                                            <Label Content="Room" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
                                            <Label Content="{Binding CMCourse.Course.Room, TargetNullValue='No room set'}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
                                            <Label Content="{Binding CMCourse.Course.Description, TargetNullValue='No description set'}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Expander>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>

                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Grid.Row="1" />
                        </Grid>
<!--#endregion Custom Modification-->
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**AnnouncementView - Custom UserControl displayed by the DataGrid**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ClassroomManager.Views.AnnouncementView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ClassroomManager.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
        <!-- Row 0 -->
        <Image x:Name="ProfilePic" Source="{Binding OwnerProfilePicURL}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
        <Label x:Name="OwnersName" Content="{Binding OwnerName}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Label Content="State" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />

        <!-- Row 1-->
        <Label x:Name="CreationTime" Content="{Binding CreationTimeText}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Label x:Name="PostState" Content="{Binding StateText}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />

        <!-- Row 2 -->
        <TextBlock x:Name="AnnouncementText" Text="{Binding Announcement.Text}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: As i can understand , u need to be able to see your column header no matter how far you scroll down , or ?

Comment: No sorry, it’s the complete opposite. I want the header to scroll out of view. I’ve been playing around and have kind of got it working using just an ItemsControl, ScrollViewer and VirtualizingStackPanel but scrolling is not smooth even though I’ve set the ScrollUnit to Pixel. Will have to carry on with that in the morning now though. Still curious why it’s not working with the DataGrid though. Thanks.

Comment: ah, ok . If that is the case , only thing i know is that someone made sample of it and it's available on github . You can check it out, maybe u can find some points to move forward https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/ScrollHeader

Comment: if you wanna scroll the header out of view then it can be a simple row. see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62694051/366064