# How to add a textbox row inside the datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Datagrid that binds and auto generate columns. I need to add a row inside the table for searchbox in each column of DataGridTextColumn type alone.

I need to create like this in the photo below[image]

I have searched a lot but i can't find any solution for it. Anyone know how to create the textbox inside datagrid. Some links or sample codes will be helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62693340/366064

Comment: @Bizhan thanks i have checked the answer and i found it is not possible.I added the searchboxes above the header using stackpanel with the datagrid

Comment: It's not impossible, there are other workarounds such as using RowDetails. but that link was the cleanest way to do it but it may not worth it. I added an answer which I think is the easiest way to do it:

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `ItemsPanel` to create a gap for other controls:

```
    <DataGrid.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Margin="0,50,0,0"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </DataGrid.ItemsPanel>
```

Then overlay other textboxes onto the area of the `DataGrid` using a `Canvas` or any other control which has `ClipToBounds` equal to false

[image]

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ...}" >
        <DataGrid.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Margin="0,50,0,0"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </DataGrid.ItemsPanel>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ...}" x:Name="col1"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ...}" x:Name="col2"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Canvas>
        <TextBox Height="30" Width="{Binding ElementName=col1, Path=ActualWidth}" Margin="10,30,0,0"/>
        <TextBox Height="30" Width="{Binding ElementName=col2, Path=ActualWidth}" Margin="50,30,0,0"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

I'm going to skip the part where you bind the margin of each text box to the width of columns using a converter because it's entirely trivial for me to write the code.

Other workarounds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62694051/366064)